# Active Record joins where any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I have a model `Tlk`:

```
class Tlk < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :msgs
end
```

And I have a `Msg` model:

```
class Msg < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :tlk
end
```

For the `tlks#index` page, I want to only load Tlks that have > 0 `msgs`.

So far I only have:

```
Tlk.joins(:msgs)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here! I have searched for a number of similar questions, but for some reason can't draw the info I need to solve this for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your model:

```
class Tlk < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :msgs, dependent: :destroy
  scope :with_msgs, -> { joins(:msgs).distinct}
end
```

And in your tlks_controller:

```
class TlksController < ApplicationController
  # your code...

  def index
    @tlks = Photo.with_msgs
  end
 
  # your code...

end
```

if you prefer not to use scope... you can do it directly in the controller's action:

```
def index
  @tlks = Tlk.joins(:msgs).distinct
end
```

Solution tested in rails 6.0

Comment: I ended up with `@tlks = Tlk.includes(:msgs).where.not(msgs: { id: nil })`. Would I need to add something like that as when I did simply `Tlk.joins(:msgs)` I got a duplicate of every Tlk depending on the number of messages (2 Msgs in the Tlk = 2 instances of the Tlk). So does the scope handle that problem or simply provide a kind of new method to make the join neater?

Comment: sorry i forgot that .... use the .distinct method. I already edit my answer

Comment: if you prefer not to use scope... you can do it directly in the controller's action: 
`@tlks = Tlk.joins(:msgs).distinct`